# Groovy get all elements in a list under certain index

Tags: list, groovy, element

I want to collect all the elements in a specific array list under a specific index. Let's say I have this list:

```
def names = ["David", "Arthur", "Tommy", "Jacob"]
```

I want to print all the names under the index of 2, which in this case, will print "David, Arthur"

Now I can use a for loop quite easily with that or even groovy's `eachWithIndex()`. The problem is I don't want to run all over the elements because that's not efficient. Rather than that, I want to run until a specific point.

Is there any method in groovy which does that , because I didn't find one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might consider using a normal `for` loop with an `int` index instead of something *groovy* in such a case. `for (int i=0; i<2; i++)...`

Answer (score 7):

Since you're starting at index 0, the [`take`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html#take(int)) method is probably the simplest approach.

```
def names = ["David", "Arthur", "Tommy", "Jacob"]
assert ['David', 'Arthur'] == names.take(2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Given the list

```
def names = ["David", "Arthur", "Tommy", "Jacob"]
```

you can use any of the options below:

```
assert [ "Tommy", "Jacob" ] == names[ 2..<4 ]
assert [ "Tommy", "Jacob" ] == names[ 2..-1 ]
assert [ "Tommy", "Jacob" ] == names.subList( 2, 4 )
assert [ "Tommy", "Jacob" ] == names.drop( 2 )
```

Note, that each of these methods create a new List instance, so if the memory considerations are of importance, it makes sense to skip the elements using e.g. `eachWithIndex()` method or alike

Answer (score 4):

Using [Ranges](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Ranges):

```
​def names = ["David", "Arthur", "Tommy", "Jacob"]
def idx = 2

def sublist = names[0..idx-1]

sublist.each { n ->
    println n
}
```

Using more syntactic sugar:

```
names[0..<idx]
```